# Syntax error creating Graphql query in Flutter

Tags: flutter, graphql

I'm trying to pass my variable to the query object but I think I have a syntax error somewhere:

When I have the string like this (not passed to Query widget)the api call works:

```
String fetchMissingConsignments = """ query MyQuery {
  getCountMissingConsignmentNotes(accountId: "66fdc17b-308d-4e71-85ee-0d4a77e3276e")
}""";
```

But when I try to pass it to the Query widget like this:

```
   String fetchMissingConsignments = """ query MyQuery(\$accountId: String!){
          getCountMissingConsignmentNotes(where:{accountId:{ _eq:\$accountId}})
        }""";
```

I get a null back...

And the Query Object:

```
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
              child: Query(
            builder: (QueryResult result, {VoidCallback refetch, FetchMore fetchMore}) {
              final res = result.data['getCountMissingConsignmentNotes'];
    
              return Text(res.toString());
            },
            options: QueryOptions(
              
              documentNode: gql(fetchMissingConsignments),
              variables: {'accountId': '66fdc17b-308d-4e71-85ee-0d4a77e3276e'}, //pass variable here 
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
```

**PS**
Im using this graphql [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_flutter)

Answer (score 0):

The query with with variable will work inside the function/method and the value of the variable in query will be set by the parameter of the function/method, like this:

```
  searchData(String name) {
    if (name.length > 2) {
      searchQuery = '''
      query myQuery  {
      launches(where: {
      name: "$name"
     })   {
        name 
        details  
    }
  }
  ''';

      setState(() {
        this.query = name;
      });
    }
  }
```